# JavaScript dictionary data length

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

```
{
    "F1.1": {
        "add": [
            {
                "id": 169138,
                "name": "volkswagen"
            },
            {
                "id": 173212,
                "name": "skoda"
            }
        ],
        "delete": [
            {
                "id": 175555,
                "name": "mercedes"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm not been able to get length of add and delete array `F1.1` is dynamic value, hence we cannot rely on it.
How can we get the array lengths?

Comment: What *can* you rely on? Do you have some variable which tells you which property to check?

Comment: @NicholasTower - don't have any property whatsoever, I just have this object dats it

Comment: Ok, so do you want to check **every** property on the object? You said that "F1.1 is dynamic", and i'm trying to understand what restrictions that places on the solution

Comment: @JaromandaX yes

Comment: @JaromandaX Junk answer? `Object.keys(data["F1.1"]);` I can always replace `F1.1` with some dynamic value right? Why patronizing others?

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you please enlighten what solution would you provide?

Comment: In case the provided data-structure is stable but only its single first level key (here `"F1.1"`) does vary its naming, the OP should have a look into and also make use of [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) in order to always access the data structure's first and only value which is the object that carries both arrays `add` and `delete` e.g. `const { add, delete: remove } = Object.values(data)[0]; console.log({ addLength: add.length, deleteLength: remove.length });` **Warning/Note:** `delete` is a protected keyword.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```js
const data = {
    "F1.1": {
        "add": [
            {
                "id": 169138,
                "name": "volkswagen"
            },
            {
                "id": 173212,
                "name": "skoda"
            }
        ],
        "delete": [
            {
                "id": 175555,
                "name": "mercedes"
            }
        ]
    }
};

// Get the dynamic property names
const dynamicProperties = Object.keys(data["F1.1"]);

// Iterate through the dynamic properties and get the lengths
dynamicProperties.forEach(property => {
    const arrayLength = data["F1.1"][property].length;
    console.log(`Length of ${property} array: ${arrayLength}`);
});
```

Comment: @Ashok ... did you ever dive into the suggested solution of the above answer before accepting it. The approach just downright does access the property value by the `'F1.1'` key which, according to the OP, is not reliable due to its varying naming.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).